# Matrix multiplication involving the TRANSPOSE of a row

Tags: excel, matrix, transpose

I'm using Excel 2010. My example is in a spreadsheet with `1` in A1; `2` in B1, `1` in  D1; `2` in D2. When I multiply a row by a column, everything works fine:

```
=MMULT(A1:B1,D1:D2)
```

If I use the TRANSPOSE function to multiply a row by itself and put the answer in a single cell, it chokes (saying `#VALUE!`):

```
=MMULT(A1:B1,TRANSPOSE(A1:B1))
```

This seems to be because it wants to produce the same answer twice. Selecting two cells, typing the formula in the top one then linking them with CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER (which adds curly brackets to the formula) gives the correct answer twice:

[image: {=MMULT(A1:B1,TRANSPOSE(A1:B1))}]

Out of curiosity, I tried `=MMULT(A1:B1,TRANSPOSE(TRANSPOSE(D1:D2)))`. It also wanted to repeat the answer.

[(screenshots of all five examples are together here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVWkb.png)
[image: screenshots of all five examples are together here]

While I realise I can just copy the duplicated answer to a scrap area and then collect a single cell from there, that seems a bit messy. And, more seriously, I'm worried about whether other strange things happen when matrix functions are chained an Excel.

Is there a way to suppress the duplication so multiplying one row by one column gives one answer, or have I misunderstood everything?

Comment: You don't need to select 2 cells to Ctrl+Shift+Enter (CSE) your formula. You can CSE it in a single cell to get correct result.

Comment: Thanks BrakNicku, that works and makes sense. I thought I had already tried it, but clearly I am being particularly dim today.

Answer (score 1):

You have to transpose the matrix first in the worksheet and then multiply the original matrix with the transpose as you have done in

```
=MMULT(A1:B1,D1:D2)
```

This gives the correct result without any duplication. Using the transpose function inside the mmult either chokes or creates duplicate if you select multiple cells.